# Issue displaying followed users posts. Only shows CurrentUsers posts?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My code only seems to download the currentUsers posts from parse and display them, when I'm also trying to download the users I'm following posts..?

Really need some help understanding this, if you see the problem, please let me know!!

code:

Best regards,
Theo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be a reference to the ***following*** column of `Followers` instead of the ***follower***. Look carefully at the two queries below:

```
// Query for the friends the current user is following
let followingActivitiesQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
followingActivitiesQuery.whereKey("following", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)


// Using the activities from the query above, we find all of the photos taken by
// the friends the current user is following
let photosFromFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "Object")
photosFromFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("userId", matchesKey: "following", inQuery: followingActivitiesQuery)
photosFromFollowedUsersQuery.whereKeyExists("image")
```

In particular, this line:

```
followingActivitiesQuery.whereKey("following", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
```

In the first query, the goal is to get everyone that the user is following. This means to query for all of the `Followers` objects where the ***follower*** column points to the current user. In the second query, we then match on the ***following*** column from the first query.

The first query should be:

```
followingActivitiesQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
```